# How do I export data from multiple pages into a csv file?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I am working on a scraping project, and am in the final stages. Right now, my code can navigate to the first profile, scrape the data from that profile, print that data, then move on to the next profile, and repeat the process. Now, I want to put the data I collect into a csv file instead of printing it. I am not sure how to do this, so I am looking for guidance/updates to my current code. Thank you for your help!

My current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/nzalle/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://directory.bcsp.org/")
count = int(input("Number of Profiles to Scrape: "))

body = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body") 
profile_count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@align='right']/a")

while len(profile_count) < count:   # Get links up to "count"
    body.send_keys(Keys.END)
    sleep(1)
    profile_count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@align='right']/a")

for link in profile_count:   # Calling up links
    temp = link.get_attribute('href')   # temp for
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")   # open new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])   # focus new tab
    driver.get(temp)

    # scrape code

    Name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[2]/div').text
    IssuedBy = "Board of Certified Safety Professionals"
    CertificationorDesignaationNumber = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[2]').text
    CertfiedorDesignatedSince = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div[2]').text
    try:
        AccreditedBy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/div[2]/a').text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        AccreditedBy = "N/A"

    try:
        Expires = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/div[2]').text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        Expires = "N/A"

    Data = (Name + " , " + IssuedBy + " , " + CertificationorDesignaationNumber + " , " + CertfiedorDesignatedSince + " , " + AccreditedBy + " , " + Expires)

    print(Data)

    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.close()
```

Comment: You should look into pandas, you can store your data into a DataFrame object using column names. You can then save the DataFrame as a .csv. Some quick googling on pandas dataframe will probably help you along quite a bit.

Comment: Will do! Do you have any guidance in integrating pandas with my current code?

Comment: I would store all your information in one big list and then convert that list to a dataframe. How you convert that is shown in: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26333/convert-a-list-of-lists-into-a-pandas-dataframe